# Custom Validator Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript

I've written a web api function that takes a username from the textfield and checks if the username is already taken. To know if the username is available or not, my server returns `Y` if it is available and `N` if its not.

To validate the username, I'm using a ValidatorFn in Angular2 so validate the input. However, my validator function is not working.

Here is the validator function:

```
interface Validator<T extends FormControl> {
  (c: T): { [error: string]: any };
}

function validateUsername(c: string) : ValidatorFn {
  return (this.isAvailable(c)=='Y') ? null : {
    validateUsername: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```

Here is the isAvailable function:

```
private isAvailable(username: string) {
  let usernameAvailable;
  let url = 'URL/api/auth/checkuser/' + username;
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
  headers.append('Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
  headers.append('AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.get(url, options)
    .subscribe((res: Response) => usernameAvailable);
  return usernameAvailable; //returns Y or N
}
```

Form Builder:

```
complexForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private http: Http, fb: FormBuilder) {

  this.complexForm = fb.group({
    'username': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10), validateUsername(this.complexForm.controls['username'].value)])],
  })
}
```

`validateUsername(this.complexForm.controls['username'].value)` is failing and I'm getting this error:

```
[ts] Type '{ validateUsername: { valid: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validateUsername' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn'. (property) validateUsername: {
    valid: boolean;
}
```

Comment: but isn't validateUsername a ValidatorFn? I figured ValidatorFns return null if they are passed and false if failed

Comment: @Vega   I just attempted, it still doesn't accept a boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You not adding your validator function correctly. You don't need to call your function when you register it:

```
this.complexForm = fb.group({
  'username': [null, Validators.compose(
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5),
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      validateUsername    <----- don't call it here
    ]
  )],
})
```

You can see that some functions are called:

```
Validators.minLength(5),
```

But that is factory function call and not a validator function call. During initialization they return `ValidatorFn`:

```
  /**
   * Validator that requires controls to have a value of a minimum length.
   */
  static minLength(minLength: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
       ...
  }
```

See more [in the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators).

Also, it seems that your validator is async, so you have to pass it in the async array. And I don't think you need `Validators.compose`. The correct configuration should therefore be like this:

```
this.complexForm = fb.group({
  'username': [null, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(5),
    Validators.maxLength(10),
  ], [validateUsername]]
})
```

Regarding the error:

> Type '{ valid: boolean; }' is not assignable to type `ValidatorFn`.

You need to use the correct return type `ValidationErrors` instead of `ValidatorFn`:

```
function validateUsername(c: string) : ValidationErrors {
  return (this.isAvailable(c)=='Y') ? null : {
    validateUsername: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarfiying the validator function call.
however I'm still having an issue with the function itself.

This error to be precise:
[ts]
Type '{ valid: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'valid' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn'.



it says valid is not a type of validatorFn however its used normally in the docs..

Comment: you specified the wrong return type, use `ValidationErrors` instead of `ValidatorFn`. I updated my answer

Comment: Would the string set to false return an invalid flag for the custom validator?

Comment: what string? check my udpated answer, the type was incorrect. You need to use the correct return type `ValidationErrors` instead of `ValidatorFn`

Comment: Yeah I noticed, thanks again for the help. The validator is working now however I'm now facing a different issue that I'm not able to get the username to be passed into the validator from the textfield.

You solved my initial issue. thanks :)

Comment: @M.Itani, you're welcome, post a link here if you create another related question